# iPhone: Jump to next uitextfield in uitableview, how to?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextfield

In my iPhone project I'm using a UITableview with UITableViewCells containing UITextfields. I have seen in many apps that it is possible to use a next button to jump to the next textfield in the next cell. What is the best way to accomplish this?

My idea is to get the indexPath of the cell with the textfield that is being editing and then get the next cell by cellForRowAtIndexPath. But how can I get the indexPath of the cell I'm currently editing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Keep references to the `UITextField` instances in your table view.
2. Assign unique tag values to your `UITextField` instances.
3. In your last text field, you might set its Return key type, which changes the keyboard's Return key label from "Next" to "Done": `[finalTextField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];`

In the `UITextField` delegate method `-textFieldShouldReturn:`, walk through the responders:

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)tf {
    switch (tf.tag) {
        case firstTextFieldTag:
            [secondTextField becomeFirstResponder];
            break;
        case secondTextFieldTag:
            [thirdTextField becomeFirstResponder];
            break;
        // etc.
        default:
            [tf resignFirstResponder];
            break;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I'm just keeping track of the current textfield as there is many textfields. Can I in some way get the next textfield without using tags?

Comment: Sure, just keep references to them, `UITextField *firstTextField`, or use an array, etc. But tags are probably the fastest way to identify the delegate's text field.

Comment: But if I don't want to keep track of all textfields or tags? Can I in some way get the current cell that the currently editing textfield is in and then get the indexpath?

Comment: If you have selection enabled on the cell, you might be able to do something with the `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath` method but that has nothing to do with a text field, per se.

Comment: I wonder if there is no other way - when running the emulator under XCode, you can jump from field to field with "tab" on the hardware keyboard... But I don't have any clue if that's available to us mere mortals

Comment: i don't think it is a good way to keep track of every textfield instance in the tableView

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the UITextField was added to the UITableViewCell like below

```
UITableViewCell *cell;
UITextField *textField;
...
textField.tag = kTAG_TEXTFIELD;
[cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
...
```

You can get the current index path via

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
  if([textField.superView.superView isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)textField.superView.superView;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
  }
  ...
```

The next row's UITextField would then be

```
NSIndexPath *indexPathNextRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(indexPath.row+1) inSection:indexPath.section];
UITableViewCell *cellNextRow = (UITableViewCell *)[self.myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPathNextRow];
UITextField *textFieldNextRow = (UITextField *)[cellNextRow.contentView viewWithTag:kTAG_TEXTFIELD];
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: In iOS7 you will need to replace textField.superView.superView with textField.superView.superView.superView